# Generating Signed APK with no key store password

Tags: android, google-play, apk, signed-apk

I got a half completed project 7 months ago that was made with `Android Studio` and they had also generated a singed `APK` and put it on the Google Play Store.

Now that I have finally finished the project I would like to place it on the Google Play Store or update the project that they had put in the `Play Store`.

They gave me their Google Play Store username and password so I can access the app but they forgot to save the `key store password` they signed the APK with.

Now I have found myself in a position where I cannot generate a signed APK to put it the Play Store nor can I update the existing app.

If possible I would like to update the existing version but if not then putting a new app on the store will suffice.

What can or what should I do in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, since Android requires that all APKs are digitally signed with a certificate, **you can't publish a new version of the app without the keystore**.

As stated on the docs:

> Loss of the app signing key means that an app cannot be updated, so it is critical for it not to be lost.

You'll have to create a new Keystore and republish the app. Also, don't forget to backup this new one, and to store the password somewhere safe.

Take a look [at the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing). There are currently two ways of signing and publishing your apps throught the keystores.

The first way is to create and handle the keystore yourself, like it was done in the past.

The second way is [to use Google Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#google-play-app-signing).

> When using Google Play App Signing, you will use two keys: the app
>   signing key and the upload key. Google manages and protects the app
>   signing key for you, and you keep the upload key and use it to sign
>   your apps for upload to the Google Play Store.

The main advantage of this method is:

> When you use Google Play App Signing, **if you lose your upload key, or
>   if it is compromised, you can contact Google to revoke your old upload
>   key and generate a new one**. Because your app signing key is secured by
>   Google, you can continue to upload new versions of your app as updates
>   to the original app, even if you change upload keys.

Since you're going to have to republish the app, consider using the second option instead.

Comment: I have seen the guides to creating a new Key Store but they all say that my password is wrong. What password do i need to use there or is it because i need to also change the Key store path?

Comment: Creating a new keystore won't work to update a currently published app.

Comment: That I understood but how can I create new keystore if it says the password is incorrect. (I am trying to create a new keystore with Android Studio)

Comment: Alright those were stupid questions since I was trying to generate a Signed APK with the previous `Key store path`, now that I changed that it allowed me to generate it

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you're trying to create a new keystore? **Edit:** Ah, now it makes sense.

Comment: One more question if I may ask. I generated a singed APK and set the `Key Store path` to a folder, but now that I have generated the APK, the folder is empty?

Comment: Wait. The new keystore is missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179053/discussion-between-kataroty-and-mauker).